# How to add WYSIWYG functionality on my custom Magento 2 module?

Tags: magento2, module, admin, wysiwyg

Today I'm using the **textarea** to fields in my custom module, but I want to improve with the WYSIWYG.

How could I use WYSIWYG in a custom field in the admin configuration panel that my module creates?

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Add following code in your file.

```
app/code/Namespace/Modulename/Block/Adminhtml/ModuleFolder/Edit/Tab/Main.php
```

---

```
protected $wysiwyg;

public function __construct(
    \Magento\Cms\Model\Wysiwyg\Config $wysiwyg
    ){
       $this->wysiwyg = $wysiwyg;
     }

$fieldset->addField(
            'fieldname',
            'editor',
            [
                'name' => 'fieldname',
                'label' => __('Fieldname'),
                'title' => __('Fieldname'),
                 'config'    => $this->wysiwyg->getConfig(),
                'wysiwyg'   => true
            ]
        );
```

Done. You can see WYSIWYG in your Admin form of your Custom Module.