# Magento 2 – How to add WYSIWYG editor in admin configuration options?

Tags: magento2, admin-panel, wysiwyg

How to add WYSIWYG editor with **textarea** in the admin system configuration options?

Answer (score 3):

Open your module **system.xml** from **app/code/NameSpace/ModuleName/etc/adminhtml** and add following code:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="../../../Config/etc/system_file.xsd">
    <system>
        <section id="yoursectionid" translate="label" type="text" sortOrder="10" showInDefault="1" showInWebsite="1" showInStore="1">
            <label>Custom Label</label>
            <tab>tabname</tab>
            <resource>NameSpace_ModuleNmae::config_modulename</resource>
            <group id="general" translate="label" type="text" sortOrder="1" showInDefault="1" showInWebsite="1" showInStore="1">
                <label>General Settings</label>
                <!-- WYSIWYG editor field code start-->
                <field id="editor_textarea" translate="label comment" sortOrder="1" type="editor" showInStore="1" showInDefault="1" >
                    <label>WYSIWYG Editor</label>
                    <frontend_model>NameSpace\ModuleName\Block\Adminhtml\System\Config\Editor</frontend_model>
                </field>
                <!-- WYSIWYG editor field code end-->
            </group>
        </section>
    </system>
</config>
```

Now create the editor class file `Editor.php` at **app/code/NameSpace/ModuleName/Block/Adminhtml/System/Config** folder where we create the WYSIWYG-Editor element:

```
<?php
namespace NameSpace\ModuleName\Block\Adminhtml\System\Config;

use Magento\Backend\Block\Template\Context;
use Magento\Cms\Model\Wysiwyg\Config as WysiwygConfig;
use Magento\Config\Block\System\Config\Form\Field;
use Magento\Framework\Data\Form\Element\AbstractElement;

class Editor extends Field
{
    protected $_wysiwygConfig;

    /**
     * Editor constructor.
     * @param Context $context
     * @param WysiwygConfig $wysiwygConfig
     * @param array $data
     * @codeCoverageIgnore
     */
    public function __construct(
        Context $context,
        WysiwygConfig $wysiwygConfig,
        array $data = []
    ) {
        $this->_wysiwygConfig = $wysiwygConfig;
        parent::__construct($context, $data);
    }

    protected function _getElementHtml(AbstractElement $element)
    {
        // set wysiwyg for element
        $element->setWysiwyg(true);

        // set configuration values
        $element->setConfig($this->_wysiwygConfig->getConfig());

        return parent::_getElementHtml($element);
    }
}
```

Please let me know if you find any problem.

Comment: It almost works fine. But "Insert Variable" button doesn't work. It throws error: "Uncaught ReferenceError: MagentovariablePlugin is not defined"

Comment: Try below link : https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/175981/how-to-add-wysiwyg-functionality-on-my-custom-magento-2-module

Comment: How did you fixed that issue @Roman snitko

Comment: I am also facing the same issue..

Comment: @aravind I didn't go more in-depth and removed that button.

Answer (score 1):

Use this code:

**Step 1:**

Create your `system.xml` under

> **app/code/[Name_Space]/[Your_Module]/etc/adminhtml**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="../../../Config/etc/system_file.xsd">
<system>
     <section id="yoursectionid" translate="label" type="text" sortOrder="10" showInDefault="1" showInWebsite="1" showInStore="1">
         <label>Custom Label</label>
         <tab>tabname</tab>
         <resource>[Name_Space]_[Your_Module]::config_[your_module]</resource>
         <group id="general" translate="label" type="text" sortOrder="1" showInDefault="1" showInWebsite="1" showInStore="1">
             <label>General Settings</label>
             <!-- WYSIWYG editor field code start-->
             <field id="editor_textarea" translate="label comment" sortOrder="1" type="editor" showInStore="1" showInDefault="1" >
                 <label>WYSIWYG Editor</label>
                 <frontend_model>[Name_Space]\[Your_Module]\Block\Adminhtml\System\Config\Editor</frontend_model>
             </field>
             <!-- WYSIWYG editor field code end-->
         </group>
     </section>
</system>
</config>
```

**Step 2:**

Now we create Editor class in file `Editor.php` under

> **app/code/[Name_Space]/[Your_Module]/Block/Adminhtml/System/Config**

folder where we create **WYSIWYG** editor element

```
<?php

namespace [Name_Space]\[Your_Module]\Block\Adminhtml\System\Config;

use Magento\Backend\Block\Template\Context;
use Magento\Cms\Model\Wysiwyg\Config as WysiwygConfig;
use Magento\Config\Block\System\Config\Form\Field;

class Editor extends Field
{
    /**
     * @var WysiwygConfig
     */
    private $wysiwygConfig;

    /**
     * Editor constructor.
     * @param Context $context
     * @param WysiwygConfig $wysiwygConfig
     * @param array $data
     */
    public function __construct(
        Context $context,
        WysiwygConfig $wysiwygConfig,
        array $data = []
    ) {
        $this->wysiwygConfig = $wysiwygConfig;
        parent::__construct($context, $data);
    }

    protected function _getElementHtml(\Magento\Framework\Data\Form\Element\AbstractElement $element)
    {
        // set wysiwyg for element
        $element->setWysiwyg(true);
        // set configuration values
        $element->setConfig($this->wysiwygConfig->getConfig($element));

        return parent::_getElementHtml($element);
    }
}
```